# Linux - Old MacBook Air - SSD not found

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, ssd, linux-mint

I have a MacBook Air that only supports macOS Catalina.
I tried 'upgrading' it by installing Linux Mint on it.
That worked fine for a while, untill it crashed, and now it won't boot again.

I tried a lot of different things, but I always run into the same problem: the SSD is not recognized.

1. Booting the Mac from a Gparted live USB => it only finds the USB from which it booted
2. Booting from an Ubuntu USB => it only finds the USB from which it booted

However: I do know that the SSD is not broken, because I can still boot into some kind of macOS recovery mode.  The MacBook boots without any external device plugged in.  So I suppose the SSD is still functioning, and there's a functioning recovery partion.
However, when I use this, connect to the internet, and try to install macOS this way => again no hard disk is found to install it on.

I think that the partion with Linux Mint on it, which was formatted entirely for Linux Mint (ext4) is somehow locked.

Any ideas on how to use it again?  As stated:

- I already experimented with Linux live USB's, but:
- Gparted didn't show the disk
- sudo fdisk -l didn't show the disk
- ...

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: some more details:

When using macOS recovery, only a partition of 1.19 GB is visible, not the entire 512 GB SSD.
[macOS recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vohz.jpg)

When using Linux live USB's, I always get error messages during boot:
[Linux Live USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNul7.jpg)

Update 2023-10-31: this is the result of running "Boot Repair" http://sprunge.us/CQguef  The 512 GB SSD isn't shown in this report.

Comment: Have you tried attempting to install the version of MacOS it was supplied with? There was also a utilty called called 'rEFIt' that did a fair bit of boot manipulation .... The SSD on this one is bespoke and they last about the same as a mechanical. At least it is removable. I remember buying a very expensive caddy that would only fit that model just so I could support them for my work - I remember having to use this when mine exhibited the same behaviour.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I tried installing the original macOS (Mountain Lion), but that version also doesn't recognize the SSD.  I will look into http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/.  I read on the rEFIt website that that is the successor.

Comment: Bear in mind that those SSD's are very sensitive on the boot area, and trying to dual boot my old macbook air killed it - earlier airs have a SD card slot and there are half height SD cards designed especially to go into the slot without it sticking out. The mac runs better than expected from a class 10 128gb SD.